# How to add MongoDB database context into startup .netcore

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core

I'm using MongoDB in my project, I have created a DB context like this:

```
public class PortfolioDbContext
{
    public readonly IMongoCollection<PortfolioData> _portfolioCollection;

    public PortfolioDbContext()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        _portfolioCollection = client.GetDatabase("portfolioServiceDb").GetCollection<PortfolioData>("Portfolios");
    }
}
```

I was to inject it into my repository class:

```
    public PortfolioDbContext _db;

    public DataService(PortfolioDbContext _db)
    {
        _db = this._db;
    }
```

but `db` returns null, I thought I need to register it in my startup:

```
 services.AddSingleton<PortfolioDbContext>();
```

but I'm still getting null, any idea why?

Comment: Try `this._db = _db` in the constructor of DataService.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the constructor of `DataService`. Your are assigning `this._db` (the variable of the class) to _db (the argument of the constructor), instead of the other way around. As the default of `public PortfolioDbContext _db` is `null` and you are never assigning a different value to it, it remains `null`.

The coding guidelines from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions recommends using camel case with a `_` prefix for private variables in a class and method parameters with camel case (without underline). This helps preventing issues like this.

Your `DataService` could look like this:

```
public class DataService
{
    private PortfolioDbContext _db;

    public DataService(PortfolioDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    // ... some more methods
}
```